# regex matching from the end of the string , how to make it search from beginning

Tags: regex

Pattern is `.*,(.*),.*`, String is

> hello,i'm,kavya,this,is,test,case

match found is "test"

How do I get it matched with "i'm"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? It's unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

**If I don't missunderstood your requirements** then try this way to capture words with single quotes.

```
([\w]+['][\w]+)
```

**REGEX:** https://regex101.com/r/P2TpEu/1

Answer (score 0):

You're using `.*`, which is a *greedy* quantifier.
Use a *reluctant* quantifier.

```
.*?,(.*?),.*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Y7HjH9ybV2114e) matching `"I'm"`.

The quantifier `*` consumes as *much* as possible while still allowing the entire expression to match, whereas the quantifier `*?` consumes as *little* as possible.

A reluctant quantifier is used in both the leading and captured sub-expressions so neither advance past a comma.